# How call function getCenter() and others in react-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I tried:

```
<GoogleMap
  defaultZoom={14}
  center={{lat: props.mapCenter.lat, lng: props.mapCenter.lng}}
  onCenterChanged={getCenter()}
/>
```

**Update**: I am using a `Stateless Functional Component`:

```
const MarkerClustererExampleGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (

    <GoogleMap 
        defaultZoom={14} 
        center={{lat: props.mapCenter.lat, lng: props.mapCenter.lng}} 
        onCenterChanged={getCenter()} 
    >
)
```

But I get the error:

> getCenter is undefined.

How to resolve this problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can call functions like `getCenter()`, `getZoom()`, `getBounds()` etc from the map API via a React `ref` to the map component

Here is a rough example, note this is an untested snippet and should be considered pseudocode, but it hopefully gives you the idea of how to get this set up:

```
let ref

...

<GoogleMap 
  ref={(mapRef) => ref = mapRef} // bind the ref
  onCenterChanged={() => {
    ref.getCenter() // get the center, zoom, whatever using the ref
  }}
/>
```

There are more detailed examples of how to do this in the documentation, for example [here](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#searchbox).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like this:

```
onCenterChanged={this.getCenter}
```

**Note**: `onCenterChanged` is a event, so make sure you defined the binding in the constructor, like this

```
this.getCenter = this.getCenter.bind(this);
```

or you can use `arrow function` also, By `Arrow Function:`

```
onCenterChanged={ (e)=> this.getCenter(e)}
```

**Update:** You didn't mention that your are using `Stateless Functional Component`, whenever asking ques, try to provide the complete information.

Check this, how to define the `function` inside `Stateless Functional Component`:

```js
var App = () => {

   var click = function() {
      console.log('a');
   }
   
   return(
      <div onClick={click}> Click </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Oh, I could use like your resolve, but I have stateless component. And my variable "this" is not defined. I use component GoogleMap without variable "this"

`const MarkerClustererExampleGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={14}
    center={{lat: props.mapCenter.lat, lng: props.mapCenter.lng}}
    onCenterChanged={console.log("this", this)}
  >`

Comment: @cm-brain check the updated answer, how to define function inside stateless functional component. Write it in the same way it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example: [Adding a places search box](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/places/search-box). 
This part of the code will show  you the right path )

```
handleMapMounted(map) {
  this._map = map;
}

handleBoundsChanged() {
  this.setState({
  bounds: this._map.getBounds(),
  center: this._map.getCenter(),
});
}
```