# How can I get the current map center coordinates using getCenter in @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I am working with `GoogleMap` component from `@react-google-maps/api`, but can't seem to find how can I get the currently centered map coordinates (lat & lng) after I have moved it?

By searching around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513518/how-call-function-getcenter-and-others-in-react-google-maps) article, which asks a similar question, but none of the answers work for me. Below is a code I'm testing.

```
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
});

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <>
            <GoogleMap
                zoom={8}
                center={{lat: 35.6676095, lng: 139.334863}}
                // onCenterChanged={getCenter} - doesn't work
                // onCenterChanged={getCenter()} - doesn't work
                // onCenterChanged={this.getCenter} - doesn't work
                // onCenterChanged={ (e)=> this.getCenter(e)}  - doesn't work
            >
            </GoogleMap>
        </>
    );
}
```

The map loads fine, but once I add the `onCenterChanged=` prop, everything breaks because the `getCenter` function is obviously not declared.

I'd like to get a variable or state with the center coordinates after I have moved the map. Where do I declare it and how do I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the instance of the map during onLoad then use a state that will save this instance with initial value of null. In your `onCenterChanged` function, check if the value of your map's instance is not null then get its new center. This is achieved using the following [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-center-changed-pm6a5a?file=Map.js) and code snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap } from '@react-google-maps/api';
const defaultLocation = { lat: 11.174036305817275, lng: 76.3754534171875 };

function Map() {
  const [mapref, setMapRef] = React.useState(null);
  const handleOnLoad = map => {
    setMapRef(map);
  };
  const handleCenterChanged = () => {
    if (mapref) {
      const newCenter = mapref.getCenter();
      console.log(newCenter);
    }
  };

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      center={defaultLocation}
      zoom={8}
      onLoad={handleOnLoad}
      onCenterChanged={handleCenterChanged}
      mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '88vh' }}
    />
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Only thing is, my development environment returned some `_.zf` objects instead of lat long coordinates like in your example, but if I update the `console.log(newCenter)` to `console.log(newCenter.lat(), newCenter.lng())` I get the desired result. Thank you!